# Using auto_increment primary key instead of custom PK

Tags: mysql, sql, primary-key, auto-increment

Is it recommended to always use auto_increment for primary key over customized primary keys? E.g using

```
Create table Product)
Id int unsigned not null auto_increment,
ProductId int not null,
name varchar(30) not null,
PRIMARY KEY(Id),
UNIQUE KEY(ProductId));

Sample Data:
1, 80001, laptop
2, 80002, cell phone
3, 80003, pencil
```

instead of

```
Create table Product)
ProductId int unsigned not null,
name varchar(30) not null,
PRIMARY KEY(ProductId));

Sample Data:
80001, laptop
80002, cell phone
80003, pencil
```

Is the auto_increment primary key really a big thing in mysql database design that the first table should be considered over the second table? If so, what are some of the reason for that choice?

Comment: Let's say in 5 years, someone decides to recycle 80003 b/c they they no longer sell pencils and now sell thumb drives (they become 80003).  What will you do then?  With an independent PK, you just drop the UNIQUE KEY on ProductId and move on.  With the second, you're in a quandry. I think of it as protection against the unforeseen business rules.

Comment: What if you want to join a second table (e.g product_order) to the product table, can i use ProductId as foreign key in product_order instead of Product.Id? Assuming ProductId does not have null values since UNIQUE Keys can have null values?

Comment: If the fields match up, you can join.  Doesn't matter what they are called.

Comment: I know that the field names do not matter. However, ProductId in the first table is not a primary key but just a unique key in the table.

Comment: There is no difference according to performance if you join over a PRIMARY KEY or a UNIQUE INDEX. As to your question: Since the 1st table layout stores an additional int per row and the 2nd dont: Use 2nd layout -> smaller data -> faster access. A "someone" deciding to re-use a ProductId simply has to analyse the Impact of such a descision.